# How to store large number of database files in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a library app where I store different books as sqlite dbs. The number of books can go on increasing and this gives `SqliteFullException` when internal storage is used. If I use external storage then is there a way that the user won't be able to access these files? Also, what is the best way to save such large number of databases without exposing them to users?

Comment: Why are you afraid of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tough call. currently there is no protection in sdcard.
the internal memory is limited.

if your db file is limited in size <10 mb you can encrypt them and put it in the sdcard, and decrypt it when you want. the size limit is for the decryption time. larger files take longer to decrypt.

currently only security through obscurity is possible.

**EDIT**

as for your large you can have one db per book.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a webservice where you store all your data and let the client(phone) request the needed info from the webservice. You can protect your data by building authentication functionality into your webservice.